# Using cpp files in Android app

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to use [these cpp files](http://answers.opencv.org/question/22941/sauvola-thresholding-for-android/) in my Android app. After adding them, I am getting the error `Can't resolve type ...` for the variables. I want to know if I am adding them correctly into my application.

The `thresholder.cpp` and `thresholder.h` files are located in `/app/src/main/cpp/`. There is also a `CMakeLists.txt` file there with the contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(thresholder SHARED
        thresholder.cpp)

target_link_libraries(thresholder
                  android
                  log)
```

In my `build.gradle` file, I have (it is copied from the [Hello JNI sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-jni/app/build.gradle) )

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang'
        }
    }

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
productFlavors {
    arm7 {
        // in the future, ndk.abiFilter might also work
        ndk {
            abiFilter 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
    arm8 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
    arm {
        ndk {
            abiFilter 'armeabi'
        }
    }
    x86 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter 'x86'
        }
    }
    x86_64 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter 'x86_64'
        }
    }
    mips {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'mips', 'mips64'
        }
    }
    universal {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'mips', 'mips64', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was making an Android app with c++ files, I had to crate a jniLibs folder in the root of my project and paste there all the libs of my device's architecture (armeabi-v7a). Did you do any of that?

Additionally, what are the types of variables that cause this error?